# No module named 'scikit' using anaconda

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

I installed `scikit-learn` using command `conda install scikit-learn` and it is available under my anaconda installation folder.

However, after running python (Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)) I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'scikit'
```

I have the environment variables:

```
PYTHONHOME = C:\Users\Lejla\Anaconda3
PYTHONPATH = C:\Users\Lejla\Anaconda3\Lib
```

And also I have these included in my `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\Lejla\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Lejla\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Lejla\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
```

Comment: Have you installed numpy and scipy beforehand ?

Comment: Have you tried pip install scikit-learn ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `scikit-learn` package isn't imported via the name `scikit`. You should use `sklearn` during your import, that is:

```
>>> import sklearn
```

Take a look at [their documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#loading-an-example-dataset) while you're using it, details (among the being how to import it) are clearly shown there.